# Changing an Image's Color

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I have a series of icons that contain 1 primary color.  For example, I have a star which is yellow with a transparent background that is anti-aliased.

Is there a way to alter the hue or saturation to change the image to be purple instead?

I'm using C# 4.0, I don't care if the solution is GDI+ or WPF.  I've been using System.Drawing.Image to read the file, but I don't necessarily need to continue doing so.  The images are relatively small less than 100x100 and I want the color to be dynamic so just editing the image itself to make a bunch of copies isn't really a solution.

There is the ColorMatrix class but I'm unsure of how to convert from one color to another using it.  It looks fairly easy to just make the rgb values different, but how could I convert between colors?

Comment: @DanielA.White: I have the setPixel() method hacked together to work now, but it takes too long.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow this link for an amazing guide on image processing in C#.  If you browse the user who submitted it you can find all 6 parts of the guide.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1989/Image-Processing-for-Dummies-with-C-and-GDI-Part-1

The guide shows you how to use unsafe code to access the image data.  I prefer to keep the code safe and use the alternate method as follows:

```
        Bitmap b = new Bitmap(img1);
        BitmapData bitmapData = b.LockBits(
            new Rectangle(0, 0, b.Width, b.Height),
            ImageLockMode.ReadWrite,
            PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb
        );

        int numPixels = b.Width * b.Height;
        byte[] pixels = new byte[numPixels * 3]; // 3 bytes per pixel

        Marshal.Copy(bitmapData.Scan0, pixels, 0, pixels.Length);

        // Use this method to apply an effect to each pixel individually
        for (int i = 0; i < pixels.Length; i++)
        {
            byte value = pixels[i];
            // modify value
            pixels[i] = value;
        }

        // Use this method to apply an effect that considers RGB relationship
        byte red, green, blue;

        for (int i = 0; i < pixels.Length; i += 3)
        {
            blue = pixels[i];
            green = pixels[i + 1];
            red = pixels[i + 2];

            // modify values

            pixels[i] = blue;
            pixels[i + 1] = green;
            pixels[i + 2] = red;
        }

        Marshal.Copy(pixels, 0, bitmapData.Scan0, pixels.Length);

        b.UnlockBits(bitmapData);
```

Each different image processing technique is not C# specific.  With a basic understanding of the algorithms you should be able to apply it with this code.

Answer (score 2):

[image: world map]

I was used this code to change all ocean and sea colors...
Maybe it is a little bit longer but I think this will help you...

First I get all pixels in noktalar List

```
List<Nokta> noktalar = new List<Nokta>();


Bitmap bm = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Image);
for (int i = 0; i < pictureBox1.Height; i++)
{
     for (int j = 0; j < pictureBox1.Width; j++)
     {
          Color col = bm.GetPixel(j, i);
          Nokta n = new Nokta();
          n.point.X = j;
          n.point.Y = i;
          n.renk = col;
          noktalar.Add(n);
     }
}
```

And Nokta Class:

```
public class Nokta
{
    public Point point;
    public Color renk;        
}


deniz=noktalar.FindAll(FindDeniz);


private static bool FindDeniz(Nokta n)
{
    if (n.renk.Name == "ff000080")
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

And finally change color...

```
public void changeDenizColor(Color c)
{
     Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Image);
     foreach (Nokta n in deniz)
     {
         n.renk = c;
         bitmap.SetPixel(n.point.X, n.point.Y, c);
         pictureBox1.Image = bitmap;
     }
}
```